# Thread 1 error in saving an object

Tags: ios, swift, save

Does anyone know what this means?

```
// need add clothes.category's value in order to filter by category**

    clothes.category = self.addSelectedCategory!

    context.save(nil)
```

addSelectedCategory is:

```
var addSelectedCategory : Category? = nil
```

`Category` is an entity.

I am confused on how to add a value to clothes.category

`clothes` is:

```
var clothes = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Clothes", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Clothes
```

`Category` is a relationship between 2 entities in the dataModel

I get an error at
    `clothes.category = self.addSelectedCategory!`

that states:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   ; Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: `self.addSelectedCategory = nil` and you are forced unwrapping it. that is the reason for error. If you properly initialize the `addSelectedCategory` to something non-nil. the error will go.

Comment: addSelectedCategory is equal to an entity, but the user is supposed to enter the data him or self.  I am confused and am still getting the error.

Comment: @IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
   var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
        var clothes = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Clothes", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Clothes

Comment: clothes.name = self.nameTextField.text
        clothes.frontImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.frontImageView.image, 1)
        clothes.category = self.addSelectedCategory!
  context.save(nil)
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   } }

Comment: The code above is the code for when the user taps the save button when saving an object into one of the categories that contains an image and a title. Ex: Category Cat -> a collectionView filled with images of cats -> tap an add button, enter an image and a title and save, but I got that error. @VivekMolkar

Comment: before assigning `clother.category = self.addSelectedCategory!` check if `self.addSelectedCategory` is not `nil`.